# Tab order gets refreshed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

its a small issue but am not able to clear it.

i have created a form in visual studio 2013 , its a data entry form. 
having many text boxes .. when user entering in each textboxes and by the tab key its jumping from one textbox to antoher... but when user goes to some other screen and comes back to the form the cursor point will again the first textbox (no the latest textbox the user kept his cursor) please help me out  that how can i stay the curson when switching back to the form.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the default behavior. Check if there is some piece of code responsible for it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but , i don't have any code which is affecting this issue.

Comment: if by screen you mean you leave the form and recreate it later then yes this is the default behavior - in this case you can always remember or check the last filled data-entry and then use `SetFocus`

Comment: Hi.. can you please help to get focus on this tab behavior

Comment: If an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: If it doesnt work - maybe you could say how it's not working :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep. I managed to duplicate your problem - This worked for me

Put this code in your form that you want to keep a note of the last active control - renaming the declarations and handlers of course.

As long as the original window is never closed this should work fine. The original window should be OK to be hidden though

```
Dim lastactivecontrol As Control

Private Sub Form1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
    lastactivecontrol.Focus()
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
    lastactivecontrol = Me.ActiveControl
End Sub
```